Functional equation $ L(f \circ g) = L(f) \circ L(g)$
I had a few thoughts about functional equations and asked myself the following. Let $X = C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. Is there a function $L: X \rightarrow X$ such that $(\forall f,g \in X)$:
$$
\def\id{\operatorname{id}}
\begin{align} 
i. && L(f \circ g) &= L(f) \circ L(g) \\ 
ii. && L(\id_\mathbb{R}) &= \id_\mathbb{R} 
\end{align} 
$$
holds that is non-trivial, i.e., $L \neq \id_X$. Even though it seems so trivial and I am sure that there should be such a non-trivial function. Because no special conditions were placed on $L$ apart from the equation and the normalization, so that we do not get trivial solutions like the constant functions. Nevertheless I have not yet been able to specify one. Can anyone give me any hints?

Oh man, sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees. Thank you @SassatelliGiulio

By the way, if we think of $X$ as a category with a single object and each $f$ as an arrow, the two conditions make $L$ into a functor from $X$ to itself (called an endofunctor).

No relation to category theory. You ask about non-trivial endomorphisms of a monoid. I have therefore removed the category theory tag. (Yes this may be the context, but recall that tags should be useful for the users of this site, nothing else. Also, finding such an endomorphism doesn't require category theory either. Regardless of the fact that monoids are one-object categories.)

Where is the answer being referenced? No answer has been posted. If they don't post one, you can also post one yourself. Please don't just edit the original post. The site guidelines explicitly encourage answering your own posts when you found a solution.

@MartinBrandenburg The answer has been deleted. What can I do about it? But yes, I will answer my question again later even if I wanted to at least give an answer I found through the edit.

The question has already been answered by @SassatelliGiulio. All bijective functions in $X$ induce a non-trivial $L$ by conjugation. Of course, this idea can also be extended to other spaces $X$ and achieve that $L$ is continuous/smooth etc. Whether there are other possibilities apart from conjugation, I don't know at the moment.
